# One French character in a JSON file crashes it all

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am outputting stuff from a JSON file that is parsed from a MySQL database using PHP. It contains user-inputed data. I know that the JSON is valid because I test it in a standard JSON validator and am being told: **The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication)**

I retrieve the code in my iOS app (Swift) using JSONObjectWithData as shown below.

Problem I'm having is that I only need one customer that types his name as Jürgensen, and my whole list is now broken in my app! Instead of a list of names I get a blank table. The JSON file is STILL valid, I see those characters nicely displayed if I run my JSON file directly in browser so I think it's UTF 8 compliant. To be on the safe side I'm making sure the code is compliant UTF8 wise on the PHP side as well using mysql_set_charset('utf8', $query) on my MySQL query.
 (Also above JSON validator test as above test is still ok).

So my problem must be on my Xcode side, which is the following:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.myjasonstring.com")

println("so far so good 1")


if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    {


println("so far so good 2")


if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
{


println("so far so good 3")

if let PeopleArray = json["people"] as? [NSDictionary]
            {


and so on...
```

As I want to see which part of my Swift code is choking, I am outputting those messages to the console. When I have a French character in the file  I only get past "so far so good 2". That tells me it's either  **NSJSONSerialization** or **JSONObjectWithData** (or possibly both?) that is my problem.

**EDIT:**

This would be a sample of Json code that would not work because of a single French character:

```
{"people":[ {"fname”:”Brenda ", "lname”:”Jones”, "dotrav":"2015-07-21”, "payment_description":"Cash”, "amount_paid”:”20.00", "showed_up":"0", "numofseats”:”2”, "resnum”:”1152A057733jh6541", "res_id”:”52628939", "res_notes”:””},{“fname”:”John”, "lname":"Jürgensen", "dotrav":"2015-07-23", "payment_description":"Credit Card", "amount_paid":"30.00", "showed_up":"0", "numofseats":"2", "resnum":"3434A8989835463J2", "res_id":"52628940”, "res_notes”:”Nothing special in notes”} ]}
```

Comment: It would really help if you could post a very small, complete example file that breaks the JSON parser.

Comment: Here would be a sample:

{"people":[ {"fname”:”Brenda ", "lname”:”Jones”, "dotrav":"2015-07-21”, "payment_description":"Cash”, "amount_paid”:”20.00", "showed_up":"0", "numofseats”:”2”, "resnum”:”1152A057733jh6541", "res_id”:”52628939", "res_notes”:””},{“fname”:”John”, "lname":"Jürgensen", "dotrav":"2015-07-23", "payment_description":"Credit Card", "amount_paid":"30.00", "showed_up":"0", "numofseats":"2", "resnum":"3434A8989835463J2", "res_id":"52628940”, "res_notes”:”Nothing special in notes”} ]}

Comment: What I really don't understand: If JSONObjectWithData(...) fails, why don't you use the error parameter to get information about the problem ??

Comment: I can't post the actual file of course as there is real names and other info from people there but above would be a typical sample.

Comment: You are right @Martin R, I was actually ashamed to ask that. I've seen people using JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) and similar but that is not the correct way apparently in Xcode 6.4 because it's throwing me an error: "use of unresolved identifier 'jsonerror'

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &jsonError)`   looks quite correct...

Comment: Well, my Xcode (6.4) is complaining about the &jsonError part. I'll check it again in the morning (just left my office) to see if I have typo there but I'm pretty sure that's what I typed and it didn't like it

Comment: OK, I removed "nil" from my error pointer , and according to searched suggestions I now have:

`var err: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil

if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: err) as? NSDictionary {`

The error I am so gracefully now given is exactly: **0x00000000**

Does that make sense?

Comment: @MartinR could you please see if you can help me? Thanks a million!

Comment: Same goes for @robmayoff thanks!

Comment: The JSON snippet you posted is garbled with HTML `&quot;` escapes. Edit your question to include your JSON, indented four spaces so it's formatted as code. Or put it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and post a link to the gist.

Comment: @robmayoff Let me know if this snippet is good now. In comments, Stackoverflow says to use "mini-Markdown formatting" with the "`" character to mark as code instead of 4 spaces (which they recommend in main posts)

Comment: `{"people":[ {"fname”:”Brenda ", "lname”:”Jones”, "dotrav":"2015-07-21”, "payment_description":"Cash”, "amount_paid”:”20.00", "showed_up":"0", "numofseats”:”2”, "resnum”:”1152A057733jh6541", "res_id”:”52628939", "res_notes”:””},{“fname”:”John”, "lname":"Jürgensen", "dotrav":"2015-07-23", "payment_description":"Credit Card", "amount_paid":"30.00", "showed_up":"0", "numofseats":"2", "resnum":"3434A8989835463J2", "res_id":"52628940”, "res_notes”:”Nothing special in notes”} ]}`

Comment: Edit your question to include the sample JSON. Don't put it in a comment.

Comment: regarding the simple sample - and possibly unrelated to the original issue - the sample data set appears to be full of 'smart quotes' - note the different quotes around Brenda - be sure your sample data only uses standard double quotes.  


     "fname”:”Brenda "

Comment: I would stil suspect an encoding problem is the problem is unrelated to the 'smart quotes'  - What mimetype is the file being sent using? (found in http response header) - and what is the char encoding in the http response?

Comment: var jsonError: NSError?
                var jsonResponse: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:0, error: &jsonError) as! NSDictionary

Comment: Thanks @Todd. The smart quotes are not from my original file. They came about when I edited sample information to post it here but since I took it from real data I changed people's names so the quotes became messed up. I'll try your json error throwing way though tomorrow from my office. Last time I checked, Xcode 6.4 was choking on the &jsonError part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your code to Log the error - Looks like you are having trouble with the NSError -- I'm all ObjC - but I think this is more correct in Swift.

```
var jsonError: NSError?
let jsonResponse: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: &jsonError)
if (jsonError != nil) {
    println("\(jsonError)")
}
```

Update:

I've created a playground that may help clarify what I'm assuming is happening - an encoding problem - where something is misidentifying or converting data from one character encoding to another.   You will need to ensure that the server you are downloading json from is encoding the data properly before sending - you can print out the bytes from the data following the example I have below - to check to see if the bytes coming from the server are correct - for easy of debugging - you may want to reduce the problem to a very minimal example.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

// Updated to xcode 7 & swift 2.0

import UIKit

// put a string in an array
let uUmlautArray = ["ü"]

var error:NSError?

// testData will represent utf-8 encoded
var testData:NSData?

do {
    testData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(uUmlautArray, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// a u+umlaut should encode as
// 5b = left square bracket
// 22 = double quote
// c3bc - since it's utf8 encoded - NSJSONSerialization reads/writes data as UTF8 encoded data
// 22 = double quote
// 5d = right square bracket

print("\(testData)")

// same string represented as UTF-8 with u+umlaut = 0xc3, 0xbc
var utf8EncodedData = NSData(bytes: [0x5b, 0x22, 0xc3, 0xbc, 0x22, 0x5d] as [UInt8], length: 6)
var json:AnyObject?

do {
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(utf8EncodedData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions())
} catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}


// same string encoded with latin-1 with u+umlaut = 0xfc
var latin1EncodedData = NSData(bytes: [0x5b, 0x22, 0xfc, 0x22, 0x5d] as [UInt8], length: 5)
var json2: AnyObject?
do {
    json2 = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(latin1EncodedData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions())
}  catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// server returned an invalid JSON string - it must be UTF-8 encoded - the equivalent code really should
// be done by the server

var convertString:NSString
convertString = NSString.init(data: latin1EncodedData, encoding: NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding)!

// converted data
var convertedData = convertString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
print(convertedData)

do {
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(convertedData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions())
} catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @ Todd. I'll see if my compiler lets that through. But this is a typical sample of a big problem in the iOS community in my opinion. While the seasoned developers who have been writing code for the past few years are still very comfortable in Objective-C, the newbies though, are encouraged to learn Swift as the "new" way. But when one runs into an issue, sample code is hard to find!

Comment: your code is throwing the following error:     `Cannot invoke 'JSONObjectWithData' with an argument list of type '(NSData, options: Int, error: inout NSError?)'`

Comment: Sorry, my ObjC bias was showing - replace options:0 with options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments - as you had originally.

I can appreciate the confusion of starting iOS development during this time - similar issues happened when all the good ObjC code assumed you were running on a Mac and not iOS.   Keep trying - and I'd recommend doing some basic ObjC tutorials just to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Todd.  Will check it on Wednesday and let you know. (Jewish holiday "Rosh Hashonah" tonight for 2 days )

Comment: OK @Todd. Firstly thanks for the Happy New Year wishes, I don't know why you retracted that comment though. Now, secondly going by your fixed code for the error outputting I am now getting: `(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 3506.) UserInfo=0x14e99990 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 3506.})`  So I think you were dead right on it being an encoding issue. Question is how we get the code to be UTF8 safe.

Comment: ....Let me be more specific. When we have an API written in JSON and we read from it in Xcode, in order to have that be UTF8 compliant it is necessary to declare so in the header of that document. That though immediately renders the whole script as not Json compliant alltogether, because the script will now start with headers and encoding declarations etc. instead of raw Json code. So do we declare it and then strip out everything but the Json part code then and present only that part for reading?

Comment: Not sure how/why the retraction occurred - so Happy New Year again :)

Comment: Regarding how to move forward - I guess you have two choices.  You can figure out why the server API isn't encoding the payload as UTF-8 encoded data.   Or alternatively (but not recommended) - would could convert the data from the encoding the server returned into a NSString using  stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
Then convert the NSString to NSData using a UTF8 encoding.   It's possible that you'll still have issues with other characters (perhaps nonEuropean ones) I'll update the playground with an example of this tonight.

Comment: I've updated the playground above - sorry if you aren't on xcode 7 yet - I've updated and the old swift 1.x syntax was giving me errors.  

I've added a bit of code at the end that shows how you can convert from one string encoding to another - and feed the result to the json parser.   I'll reiterate that the problem is actually on the server side - either the database has data that isn't stored as UTF8 - or the code that reads this data isn't converting from the stored string encoding the UTF8 when generating the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks, I can now confirm that I was mistaken all along. The characters are NOT utf8 safe they are charset=ISO-8859-1. Which means that even just by pulling them out in a url and trying to read them in iOS crashes and that's even before going to Json serialization. Unless I use encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding then it's fine. I will continue on Sunday using your latest string conversion code because that's exactly what I am going to need here - convert from latin1encoded to utf8

Comment: THANKS @Todd , I finally got everything to work now based on your answer. I am still on Xcode 6.4 (too risky in my opinion for newbies to jump to new versions especially Beta ones every other month) so I had to spend some hours working with your new Swift 2 code to get it working with Swift 1.2. This is what I now have:

Comment: I don't know how to get the line breaks into the commenting section here, but here goes: `if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!){
var convertString:NSString convertString = NSString.init(data: JSONData, encoding: NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding)!
var convertedData = `convertString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var jsonError: NSError?
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(convertedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary {